# UITableviewCell with UITextField switching between uikeyboard and uidatepickerview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, uipickerview

i have a table with 3 types of rows. First type contains a textfield for alphanumeric where you should write something in. Second type should contain a textfield with a number. third type contains a date.

My problem is when i tap into the first type the keyboard appears. Switching between type one and two switches the keyboard instantly from alphanumeric to numeric. How can i achieve a instantly switch from these keyboard types to a uidatepicker for type 3. The only way i found is dismissing the keyboard of the other textfield and showing an uidatepicker afterwards. But dismissing the keyboard will scroll the keyboard down. How can i achieve an instant switch?

Bevo

Answer (score 1):

Set the inputView property of the UITextField to an instance of UIDatePicker.

```
picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[picker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerValueChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
textField.inputView = picker;
```

In `pickerValueChanged`, update the text property of the textField by converting the date to a string:

```
- (void)pickerValueChanged {
    textField.text = [picker.date description];
}
```